# one function to fire on same class elements click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make controls for category list with sub-category and sub-sub-category lists.

Here's **HTML**:

```
<ul class="selectbox-ul">
    <li>
        <div>Category</div>
        <ul class="selectbox-ul-child">
            <li>
                <div>Subcategory</div>
                <ul class="selectbox-ul-child">
                    <li>
                        <div>Sub-subcategory</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <span id="trigger">icon</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span id="trigger">icon</span>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

So my shot was to add class for ul.selectbox-ul-child :

```
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");

function subCatStatus() {
    if(this.parentElement.children[1].className != "... expanded") {
        this.parentElement.children[1].className += " expanded"
    } else {
        this.parentElement.children[1].className == "..."
    };
};

trigger.addEventListener("click", subCatStatus);
```

And it works only for first **span#trigger**(that shows subcategories), next one (for sub-subcategories) does nothing (I've also tried to use .getElementsByClassName it didn't work for any of triggers) . So i'd like to get some explanation why doesn't this one work. And some advice how to make it work.

Comment: You should only have one `#trigger` as ids are supposed to be unique

Comment: You shouldn't have many elements with same id. You need to use different selector such as class name and iterate over the matching elements adding event listener

Comment: **The reason** why having 2 elements with the same id is bad, aside from it being invalid Html, is because [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) only returns a single element and not a HtmlCollection, meaning it will return the first it comes across.

Comment: @Domenico Write that up as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The if statement looks a bit funky. Is a class value of `...` even a working thing? Ignoring that `className` returns all classes assigned to the element. Meaning you will get `selectbox-ul-child expanded` after first use, so your if statement, as is, should not work.

Comment: I should 've put correct classes in my code snippet. It works fine **if classname != selectbox-ul-child expanded** it adds expanded class, **else classname= selectbox-ul-child** returns class name back to stock string.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to take a look at the classList.toggle() native javascript method to activate/deactivate a class on an specific element https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you can't stack multiple elements with the same ID since `document.getElementById()` is not supposed to return more than one value.

You may try instead to assign the "trigger" class to each of those spans instead of IDs and then try the following code

```
var triggers = document.getElementsByClassName("trigger");

function subCatStatus() {
    if(this.parentElement.children[1].className != "... expanded") {
        this.parentElement.children[1].className += " expanded"
    } else {
        this.parentElement.children[1].className == "..."
    };
};

for(var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    triggers[i].addEventListener("click", subCatStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript getElementById returns only single element so it will only work with your first found element with the ID.

getElementsByClassName returns an array of found elements with the same class, so when adding listener to the event on element you would require to loop through this array and add individually to it.