# Fire JS code for every element with the same class

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a cart page with multiple products that have a new price. I now want to show the customer, using JS, how much he can save. For that I use my very basic knowledge of JS to write the old and new price into a variable, replace stuff I don't want in there like "€" and do my math. Then I create a new div with a certain text and how much the customer can save. What I want to achieve is that he writes that under every product.

As you can see from the snippet he only does that for the first product. I need some kind of loop or anything where he does that code for every product in the cart. So far I searched for 2 hours and couldn't find a hint. Maybe you guys and girls can help me.

```js
var neuerpreis = document.querySelector(".price.price--reduced").childNodes[2].nodeValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');

var alterpreis = document.querySelector(".price.price--reduced .price__old").childNodes[2].nodeValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');


var difference = (alterpreis - neuerpreis).toFixed(2);


var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var newContent = document.createTextNode(("You save ") + difference + (" €"));
newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
document.querySelector(".cart-item__price").appendChild(newDiv);
```

```html
<div class="cart-item ">
  <div class="cart-item__row">
<div class="cart-item__image">
  <div class="cart-item__details">
    <div class="cart-item__details-inner">
      <div class="cart-item__price">
        <div class="price price--reduced">
          <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;66,95<span class="price__old">
            <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;79,00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-item ">
  <div class="cart-item__row">
<div class="cart-item__image">
  <div class="cart-item__details">
    <div class="cart-item__details-inner">
      <div class="cart-item__price">
        <div class="price price--reduced">
          <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;100,95<span class="price__old">
            <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;79,00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is probably your friend here.

Comment: I put your question title into Google and the first result for me is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637381/one-function-to-fire-on-same-class-elements-click

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is a bit more specific and will help when debugging

Comment: give your new prices also a class then you can get the old prices and new prices build the differences and build your page based on this values

Comment: @Rojo why is getElementsByClassName more specific than querySelectorAll? The only reason I would ever user className over selectorAll is if I NEED a live nodelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use querySelecetorAll and relative addressing

I select the .cart-item__price as the relevant container

Then I set some content as default

Note I do not convert to the string (toFixed) until I want to present it.

The INTL number formatter could also be used here

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".cart-item__price")].forEach(div => {
  const neuerpreis = div.querySelector(".price--reduced").childNodes[2].nodeValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
  const alterpreis = div.querySelector(".price__old").childNodes[2].nodeValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
  const difference = alterpreis - neuerpreis;
  let newContent = document.createTextNode("No savings on this product")
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  if (difference > 0) {
    newContent = document.createTextNode(("You save ") + difference.toFixed(2) + (" €"));
  }
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

  div.appendChild(newDiv);

})
```

```html
<div class="cart-item ">
  <div class="cart-item__row">
    <div class="cart-item__image">
      <div class="cart-item__details">
        <div class="cart-item__details-inner">
          <div class="cart-item__price">
            <div class="price price--reduced">
              <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;66,95
              <span class="price__old">
                <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;79,00
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cart-item ">
  <div class="cart-item__row">
    <div class="cart-item__image">
      <div class="cart-item__details">
        <div class="cart-item__details-inner">
          <div class="cart-item__price">
            <div class="price price--reduced">
              <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;100,95<span class="price__old">
            <span class="price__currency">€</span>&nbsp;79,00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (`forEach` exists on the NodeList, no need to convert to an array)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I do this preventively. 1. Older Edge browsers do not have forEach 2. I sometimes use .map and it is a pain to remember to convert for some actions and not for others

Comment: Old edge browsers don't have forEach but have the spread syntax? say wah?

Comment: Yep. ForEach was introduced in Edge v16 and Fx 50, Chrome 51. Old I know but I was around when we had Netscape Navigator 3.2

Comment: I missed Netscape, but I had IE4 and 5 (installing IE6 on WinME broke it)

Comment: Well this did the trick for me and it works :)  and thanks for the nice addition "you dont save anything". You made my day

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".test_class");

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
el[i].innerHTML = "test"+i
}
```

```html
<div class="test_class">hey</div>
<div class="test_class">hey</div>
<div class="test_class">hey</div>
<div class="test_class">hey</div>
```

Here you go